# Is possible to let a QtCharts::QScatterSeries plot marks with a character?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, scatter-plot, qtcharts

I need make a scatter chart whose data points should be plotted with an arrow, but I don't want to use a little image, as this way would use more memory.

Can I use a single char such as "↑", "→" as the mark of my scatter series? If possible, how to do it with QtCharts?
Thanks you!

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to shift your scatter series when a plotted character ("↑", "→") have been clicked, why easily and standard, you don't use push buttons under your plot? When for example push button clicked, redraw your plot in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I want draw every points of the chart with character, not rectangle or other shape. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Ok, It is best to modify the source code of `QScatterSeries` according to your needs, [link](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/scatterchart/qscatterseries.cpp.html)